# assigning value to key as associative array in zend

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to zend framework.I found a code like this
'factories' => [stdClass::class => InvokableFactory::class,]. So is it possible to assign a value as associative array to key of an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a Zend related question but a PHP construct.

And indeed, you can nest as many things as you want in an array.

It can be associative or not (in which case you will have integer indexed arrays), can contain any type of values (array, objects, ...) but the key needs to be a scalar type (integer, string).

You can also have as many level of arrays as you want, nested array and objects are a thing.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.But in PHP array is defined using () symbol but here [ ] symbol is used why so sir.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. But this has nothing to do with the Zend Framework.

Nested associative arrays can be created to your hearts content:

```
$myArray = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => 'baz'
        'apple' => 'orange',
        'fruit' => array(
            'cherry',
            'strawberry'
        ),
    ),
);
```

For more information see the [PHP: Arrays documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).